# How to use Powershell to replace text in Word which is in single line and different line?

Tags: powershell

So I want to edit a .docx file using PowerShell: First Name, Last Name, Address, Salary, Starting Day etc.
I am a **beginner** in PowerShell so I'm not too sure about the code; so, firstly I wanted to run something that will change all the instances of the full name in the Word template.

```
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$objWord.Visible = $True
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("C:\...")
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection

$FindText = "<First Name> <Last Name>"
$ReplaceText = "Someone Something"

$ReplaceAll = 2
$FindContinue = 1
$MatchCase = $False
$MatchWholeWord = $True
$MatchWildcards = $False
$MatchSoundsLike = $False
$MatchAllWordForms = $False
$Forward = $True
$Wrap = $FindContinue
$Format = $False

$objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,
  $MatchWholeWord,$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,
  $MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,$Wrap,$Format,
  $ReplaceText,$ReplaceAll)
```

So this works for all instances of the First Name and Last Name when they are in the same line, but not when I have them in different lines underneath each other like this:

First Name

Last Name

How do I write my code so that this sort of example is included aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround seems to be working now perfectly well.
Hope this helps to someone

```
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$objWord.Visible = $True
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("Path")
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection

function wordSearch($currentValue, $replaceValue){
    $objSelection = $objWord.Selection
    $FindText = $currentValue
    $MatchCase = $false
    $MatchWholeWord = $true
    $MatchWildcards = $false
    $MatchSoundsLike = $false
    $MatchAllWordForms = $false
    $Forward = $true
    $wrap = $wdFindContinue
    $wdFindContinue = 1
    $Format = $false
    $ReplaceWith = $hash[$value]
    $ReplaceAll = 2

    $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $wrap, $Format, $ReplaceWith, $ReplaceAll)
    }

$hash = @{"<First Name>" = "Value1"; "<Last Name>"="Value2"; "<Job>"="Value3"}

foreach($value in $hash.Keys) {
    $currentValue = $value
    $replaceValue = $hash[$value]

    wordSearch $currentValue $replaceValue

    }
```