# COM Objects, Powershell 5 vs 7 and Constrained Language mode

Tags: powershell, com, powershell-7.0

I have a strange issue and wonder if anyone has any ideas. I am trying to make a powershell script that can replace text in a word document.

This script works fine on version 5 but not on version 7

[How to use Powershell to replace text in Word which is in single line and different line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316140/how-to-use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-word-which-is-in-single-line-and-differ)

The problem is the command

New-Object -ComObject word.application

In version 5 it works, but in version 7 I get

New-Object: Cannot create type. Only core types are supported in this language mode.

In both shells I get that the languagemode is Constrained.

PS C:\Windows\System32> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode

ConstrainedLanguage

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior, I get the expected "New-Object : Cannot create type. Only core types are supported in this language mode." error in 5.1 too. How are you setting the language mode?

Comment: Thanks. Good question, I will need to contact our outsourced IT service provider to find out how they have done it. 

I don't find the environment variable 
__PSLockdownPolicy

or registry keu
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\__PSLockdownPolicy

so I assume its AppLocker

Comment: I have a strong suspicion their configuration isn't working the way they expect it. What happens if you manually launch Windows PowerShell and do `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = 'ConstrainedLanguage'; New-Object -ComObject Word.Application`?

Comment: $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = 'ConstrainedLanguage'; New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Cannot set property. Property setting is supported only on core types in this language mode.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = 'ConstrainedLanguage';  ...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertySetterNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage
 
Application                       : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClas

Not able to set constrainedmode manually, but new-object OK

Comment: That formatting was horrible.  It didn't let me set the LanguageMode, but still let me create the com object. I agree with you that it looks like an issue with the applocker policy

Comment: Putting code in a comment on SO seldom produces anything readable. Edit the question and format it as code.

Comment: According to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-constrained-language-mode/ COM is blocked in Constrained Language Mode... "COM objects are blocked. They can expose Win32 APIs that have likely never been rigorously hardened as part of an attack surface.". The docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes?view=powershell-7.3#constrainedlanguage-mode also say similar (with a couple of specific exceptions), which kind of implies it *shouldn't* really even work in PS 5.1 either...

Comment: Thanks guys. I agree that its strange that it works at all in 5.1 as it should be blocked. It sounds to me that we have an AppLocker policy that is either not working as it should, or has been opened up to allow creating Com objects in v5.1. I'll get in contact with IT and see what they say.